# Close a workbook unsaved

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to open a (source) file that contains data that I open, move the entire sheet to my (destination) workbook, change the location of the (source) file, and then close the (source) file without saving any changes. When I was using .xlsx source files I had no issues with this procedure. When I changed the source files to .csv suddenly I'm getting an error when I close the source file saying "Run-time error '-214722080 (800401a8)': Automation error" At the line that throws the error, I've tried also doing "Set src = Workbooks.Close(false, filename)" which gave me an error that said there wasn't a key object.

```
    fileExists = Dir(filename)
    'Checks the above command
    If fileExists = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Performance saving
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Setting the source workbook to the files from Ignition
    Dim src As Workbook
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(filename, True, True)
    
    'Pulling in the data from the file and then closing it without saving so the data isn't deleted from the file
    src.Sheets(1).Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview")
    
    'Moves data that is already read in into the archive folder so it doesn't get in the way of future runs
    Name filename As path & "Archive\" & newk & "US1Data.csv"
    
    'Closes source workbook after its been moved, line that causes error
    src.Close savechanges:=False
```

Comment: You can't move a file that's open or "Close source workbook after its been moved". Close it first and then rename it.

Comment: Did the xlsx files have more than 1 sheet ?

Comment: So I tried moving the close workbook line to before I changed the location of the source file and it didn't work @HackSlash, it says "Run-time error '-2147221080 (800401a8)': The Key you specified was not found in the collection." It fails at the close statement

Comment: the xlsx files only contained 1 sheet, just like the csv @CDP1802

Comment: So the error is resolved? Then the question as you wrote it is closed. You will have to be more specific about what you are trying to do and not just how you intend to get there. A CSV is a text file. It can't have "sheets".

Comment: Try using Copy instead of Move `src.Sheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview")`

Comment: @HackSlash no the error isn't resolved. There was no change from the suggestion you made to me. I am currently looking at a .cvs file and there definitely is a sheet present as well as an option to add another sheet so I'm not really sure what you are suggesting.

Comment: @CDP1802 that ended up working for me once I moved the relocating line to before the close statement

Comment: I found it worked with the rename before or after the close. What I observed was after moving a sheet from a workbook with only one sheet (ie a csv file), the workbook was closed. So `src.Close savechanges:=False` was trying to close a workbook that was no longer open. Are you sure the xlsx files didn't have extra blank sheets ?

Comment: No they didn't. So basically there's an interface that collects data from hundreds of machines in a manufacturer and exports this data as an excel file with just one sheet and thousands of rows of data can within this platform you can choose how you want to export the data, csv or xlsx. Initially I had the data exported at xlsx because that's what the default was but then my coworker found that the csv takes up less space on the server we store this data, which is quickly running out of space. So that's why we made the change to csv.

Comment: @Tomastep it sounds like you need a database. You can start with [MS Access](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/access). It has methods to import data from CSV files.

Comment: @HackSlash unfortunately the company I work for doesn't use Access. They are about 10 years behind on the software and technology fronts and I have no say in what we utilize to do our jobs.

Comment: Then Access is perfect. Access is from 1992 and most would not consider it modern. It might even be dying. Seriously, a case should always be made to management that if the wrong tools for the job are used you will waste a bunch of time creating an inferior solution. I'm not sure what industry you're in but parallels can be drawn in most any industry.

Comment: @HackSlash I agree with you. Everything I've learned in my degree program has told me just that, but I'm just an intern at a company that makes documents in Excel textboxes instead of Word. I can't really work around most of the constraints here.